# Cannot open root device "ram0" attempting to netboot ubuntu server with matchbox

Tags: boot, server

I'm attempting to netboot ubuntu using [matchbox](https://github.com/poseidon/matchbox) and following [these](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64) instructions. The kernel params I used are:

```
root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=<mymirror_url>
```

Where the url is a link to the ubuntu iso. The kernel attempts to boot but crashes with an error "Cannot open root device 'ram0'".

I had extracted the vmlinuz and initrd files off of the latest ubuntu live server iso. Am I missing something to be able to boot it? Also, where are the ubuntu kernel parameters documented? I can't find them anywhere.

Is the expectation that the root file system is loaded into ram remotely? Trying to determine what the correct root argument is.